# What kind of DAL to use with BizTalk 2010

Tags: sql-server, wcf, biztalk, data-access-layer, biztalk-2010

I am thinking about replacing the business layer with BizTalk orchestrations exposed as WCF services as a standard architecture for many of our apps.  Essentially ASP.NET and WinForms apps will call these services to retrieve and update data in many of our LOB databases among other things.  Some of the services will also be exposed to partners.

As for the data access, I can certainly use the SQL Adapter, but I think it's not the cleanest way to do it, and the fact that it's tightly coupled to SQL Server also makes it a bad idea for me.  I would like to use Entity Framework based custom DAL's or perhaps generated from tools like SubSonic, etc.

Is this a good idea?  From my Google searches, I can't find many people doing this kind of thing or any comments on how it might have worked out for them.

What's your take on this?  Any ideas on where to cache data, concurrency issues, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have an easier time using straight WCF and something like NHibernate or EF.  These services consuming and returning DTO's and not raw entities.  If you do have heavy business logic or mapping that needs done, BizTalk can sit in front or with ESB even expose mapping services to your data service on the side.

Also check out the new WebApi stuff. http://wcf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

And BizTalk is not great at doing low latency ... you will get some overhead on all the service calls.

If you have to do a lot of service aggregation there *MIGHT* be a case for doing it this way ... but beware the latency and overhead you get from an integration platform that is aimed at giving you all kind of services around messaging integrity etc.